# How to resolve SQLSTATE: 42803 error with PSQLException

Tags: sql, postgresql, runtime-error, psql

I am getting SQL Error 0, SQLSTATE: 42803 for the query below

```
  select
    case when parent_id = -1 then package_name else '' end as package,
    case when parent_id <> -1 then product_name else '' end as product_in_package
    from packages_info
    where source = 24349
    order by case when parent_id = -1 then row_id else parent_id end, parent_id
```

In addition, I get PSQLException also saying column "packages_info.parent_id" must appear in the GROUP BY clause but I am not using any GROUP BY clause at all. Can anyone help me to understand why am I getting this error and how can I overcome it?

Comment: Look at the Postgres log. Best bet is the error is for a different query.

Comment: I believe that you are seeing the error because of your `ORDER BY`. This is conditional on the value of parent_id. Different parent_ids are sorted differently. This means there can be no order applied across everything and ordering can therefore only be done in groups, specifically in groups of parent_id, hence the error.

Comment: Try this : select * from (select
    case when parent_id = -1 then package_name else '' end as package,
    case when parent_id <> -1 then product_name else '' end as product_in_package,
    case when parent_id = -1 then row_id else parent_id end as fororder
    from packages_info
    where source = 24349) as drt
    order by fororder, parent_id